# How to fasten scatterplot of seaborn when there is a big data(many points) to plot?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, seaborn

I found that the `seaborn.scatterplot()` method in Python is much slower than the function `geom_point` of `ggplot2` in R when there are a large number of data points to be plotted.

For example the same data in Python(`seaborn`):

```
sample_data = data.sample(10000)
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=sample_data, x="x", y="y", hue="cate")
```

and in R(`ggplot2`):

```
sample_data <- data[sample(nrow(data),10000),]
p <- ggplot(sample_data,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=cate))
```

The former is much slower than the latter.

I wonder what causes the differences in efficiency and how to make the `seaborn` as fast as `ggplot`or even better?

Why don't I use R directly: I prefer the grammar style of Python and I could do more customization with `matplotlib` after plotting with `seaborn` while `ggplot` may not be that convenient to do this.

Comment: Note that you are calling `sns.scatterplot` with a `hue` parameter, while that isn't happening in the R code.  If there are a huge number of "cate" values, things could get slow (in that case, try `legend=False`).  Also, if `data` has a non-unique index, the latest seaborn version seems to be slow (this can be mitigated with `sns.scatterplot(data=sample_data.reset_index(), ....)`). Anyway, 10_000 points is rather small, seaborn can easily draw millions of scatter points. (By the way, you create `sample_data` but don't use it. How large is `data`?)

Comment: @JohanC Very much thanks for your comment! I'm calling `sns.scatterplot` with a `hue` param as well as a `color` param in `geom_point`. Are there any differences between them? The `data` has 6 million rows or so and I haven't yet tried to directly plot them all out(I have no idea how big data `sns` can deal with in an acceptable time before).

Comment: You are still calling `sns.scatterplot` with the original `data`, not with `sample_data` (at least in the code fragment shown). Seaborn's code with `hue` isn't always optimal in speed.  You didn't mention how many different hues there are, but you can try with `legend=False`.  If speed is really important, you can also directly call matplotlib `plt.scatter('x', 'y', c='cate', data=data)`.

Comment: @JohanC Oh yes, that's a typo. You are right, the `legend=False` makes it faster and the native `plt.scatter` is much faster. There are 10-20 different hues, and I now believe the `hue` and the legend is what make it slow. Speed is really important since the project is for a website but not just personal academic research. Thank you very much!

Comment: Testing on my laptop with the `diamonds` dataset that is build into ggplot2 and seaborn (53K rows), `scatterplot(diamonds, x="carat", y="price", hue="color")` runs in 200ms while `ggplot(diamonds, aes(c=carat, y=price, color=color)) + geom_point()` runs in 1700 ms (and seems to take longer to actually render in RStudio. So I think you'd need to a) share your data, or test with builtin datasets, b) show a full reproducible example of what you're doing, and c) get some quantitative timing estimates.

Answer (score 2):

To plot "big data" scatter points, i would suggest `Plotly` library.
It has a `Scattergl` function to manage up to billions data points.

Here's an example with 100.000 data points:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

N = 100000
r = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)
theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, N)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergl(
    x = r * np.cos(theta), # non-uniform distribution
    y = r * np.sin(theta), # zoom to see more points at the center
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=np.random.randn(N),
        colorscale='Viridis',
        line_width=1
    )
))

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's cool! I'll give it a try!